# Error "Type is not declared" when validating schema

Tags: 2011, schema

I am getting following error while updating the source of the schema. I am just updating the source and when I click on Design I am getting the error.

The source is just simple text field.

Unfortunately I cannot delete this schema because it has some any dependencies.

```
Type 'http://test.com/schemas/sdltridion:Validator' is not declared.
```

**Source:**

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://test.com/schemas/sdltridion" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://test.com/schemas/sdltridion" xmlns:tcmi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance" schemaLocation="cm_xml_inst.xsd">
</xsd:import>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="tcm:81-36890-8">
</xsd:include>
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
      <tcm:Labels xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
        <tcm:Label ElementName="label" Metadata="false">Elements label</tcm:Label>
        <tcm:Label ElementName="element" Metadata="false">Input element</tcm:Label>
        <tcm:Label ElementName="validators" Metadata="false">Validators (Only applicable on text fields)</tcm:Label>
        <tcm:Label ElementName="supporting" Metadata="false">Supporting elements</tcm:Label>
      </tcm:Labels>
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:element name="Content">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="label" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:normalizedString">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
            </tcm:ExtensionXml>
          </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="element" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="tcmi:SimpleLink">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
            </tcm:ExtensionXml>
              <tcm:linktype xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">ComponentLink</tcm:linktype>
              <tcm:AllowMultimediaLinks xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">false</tcm:AllowMultimediaLinks>
              <tcm:AllowedTargetSchemas xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                <tcm:TargetSchema xlink:href="tcm:81-36927-8" xlink:title="Schema1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              </tcm:TargetSchema>
                <tcm:TargetSchema xlink:href="tcm:81-36926-8" xlink:title="Schema2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              </tcm:TargetSchema>
                <tcm:TargetSchema xlink:href="tcm:81-36928-8" xlink:title="Schema3" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              </tcm:TargetSchema>
            </tcm:AllowedTargetSchemas>
          </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="validators" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Validator">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
            </tcm:ExtensionXml>
              <tcm:EmbeddedSchema xlink:href="tcm:81-36890-8" xlink:title="Schema4" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
            </tcm:EmbeddedSchema>
          </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="supporting" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tcmi:SimpleLink">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
            </tcm:ExtensionXml>
              <tcm:linktype xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">ComponentLink</tcm:linktype>
              <tcm:AllowMultimediaLinks xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">false</tcm:AllowMultimediaLinks>
              <tcm:AllowedTargetSchemas xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                <tcm:TargetSchema xlink:href="tcm:81-36929-8" xlink:title="Schema5" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              </tcm:TargetSchema>
            </tcm:AllowedTargetSchemas>
          </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I tried pasting the source of simple schema with Text field, even then it is giving the same error. If I start pasting this source in another schema I am also getting same error.

Even rollback top previous versions also did not work.

The schema works well in other environment with same source.

Please help em to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the embeddable schema you have on the page and with root element name Validator. Is it possible that by any chance, root element name of schema `"tcm:81-36890-8"` is no longer Validator? It would explain why it can't be found

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have the following element in your XSD which is not defined in this schema.

```
<xsd:element name="validators" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Validator">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
          <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
        </tcm:ExtensionXml>
          <tcm:EmbeddedSchema xlink:href="tcm:81-36890-8" xlink:title="Schema4" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
        </tcm:EmbeddedSchema>
      </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:element>
```

It might be defined in the `Schema` "tcm:81-36890-8" however, I would assume as you are using custom XSD type, this would make this a Complex Schema, and you cannot edit complex schema in design tab. By the way, are you able to save it.